# Do nothing if an input field is empty and if it has a value check to see if it is numeric and display an alert if it is not

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I am trying to make a form that automatically sums input fields on blur and displays the sum in an inactive "Total:" field. I don't want to run anything if a user puts focus in an input then moves focus away without inputting anything and if a user does input something I want to restrict the field to only numbers. If there is a better way of doing this, please let me know. Here is an example of my current approach:

## HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test Calc</title>
        <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Sales By Month</h1>
        <form method="get">
            <label for="january">January:</label>
            <input type="text" id="january" class="amount" onblur="isNum(); calculateSum();">
            <label for="february">February:</label>
            <input type="text" id="february" class="amount" onblur="isNum(); calculateSum();">

            <label for="total">Total:</label>
            <input type="text" id="total" disabled>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

## JavaScript

```
function calculateSum() {

    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('amount');

    var myLength = elems.length;
    sum = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < myLength; ++i) {
        sum += elems[i].value *1;
    }

    document.getElementById('total').value = sum;

}

function isNum() {
    var amounts = parseInt(document.getElementsByClassName('amount').value);

    if (isNaN(amounts) == true && amounts != '') {
        alert("Please enter a numeric value");
    }

}
```

The calculation function currently works but the "Please enter a numeric value" alert pops up every time I tab away from a field regardless of the contents.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a list, which you know, because you used it correctly in `calculateSum`. In `isNum` you are trying to get the `value` property of the _list_, so that expression is __always__ `undefined`.

Comment: Do `console.log(amounts);` just to see if its what you were looking for

Comment: +1 seems a valid question, down vote negated

Comment: @Robert check out the new update of my post ... everything works fine now http://jsfiddle.net/RNnjg/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to test the value of the element that losts focus, which means you should pass it in the argument like this

```
onblur="isNum(this); calculateSum();"
```

then in your `isNum` function in javascript remove `document.getElementsByClassName` and use the argument instead ... and don't test if `amounts != ''` because it will never be equal to empty string while you do this `amounts = parseInt(elem.value);` you have to test on the `elem.value`

```
function isNum(elem) 
{
   var amounts = parseInt(elem.value);

   if (isNaN(amounts) == true && elem.value != '') {
     alert("Please enter a numeric value");
}
```

Here is a  <kbd>**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RNnjg/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: That does work however it still fires the alert if you tab out of an input and it is blank.

Comment: No , I fixed it ... the problem was that you tested the `amounts!=''`but you should test the value of the input

Comment: I see now. Thank you for taking the time to help with such a newbie question and explaining what I did wrong!